# Is it possible to implement readdir() in Ubuntu 12.10 (kernel 3.5)?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

In 8.6 of `K & R`, the authors implemented a simple version of `readdir()`. The code is as follows:

```c
#include <sys/dir.h>   /* local directory structure */
/* readdir:  read directory entries in sequence */
Dirent *readdir(DIR *dp)
{
   struct direct dirbuf;  /* local directory structure */
   static Dirent  d;      /* return: portable structure */
   while (read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf))
                   == sizeof(dirbuf)) {
       if (dirbuf.d_ino == 0) /* slot not in use */
           continue;
       d.ino = dirbuf.d_ino;
       strncpy(d.name, dirbuf.d_name, DIRSIZ);
       d.name[DIRSIZ] = '\0';  /* ensure termination */
       return &d;
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

In my opinion, in the line with `read()`, `dp->fd` is the file descriptor of the directory. The authors used `read()` to get `struct direct` directly from the directory file.

However, in Ubuntu, it is not possible to read a directory file. When I tried to read a directory, I just got something strange.

I read in APUE that in some systems, this action is not allowed. So is there any other ways to realize my own `readdir()`?

Comment: K&R is making some platform-specific / obsolete assumptions. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html for an idea how `readdir` works on Linux these days.

Comment: Thank you @Nemo! I've read the document. It is the function `readdir()` call in Linux, right? I just want to know more about the underlying code. Maybe I should learn more about Linux and filesystem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at code from 40 years ago. Directories are simply not implemented like that on any modern platform. Read the documentation for your filesystem (ext4 if you are on Linux) if you really need to write code to manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I regarded it as a too easy problem... I will learn more about ext4.